# Output array by adding extra blank rows

Tags: google-sheets

I have this table :

[image]

if i do simple query :

```
=filter(A1:B4, A1:A4<>"")
```

it will output just like the source. But i want to make the output to add some extra blank rows like this :

[image]

How can i do it?

Comment: Please stop including "Google Sheets:" (a tag) in question titles and stop including "Thanks". For details see [What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/tagging) and [Expected behavior](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/behavior).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use insert `2` blank rows between every row in `A1:B` like this:

```
=arrayformula( 
  iferror( 
    vlookup( 
      (row(A1:B) - row(A1)) / (2 + 1) + row(A1), 
      filter( { row(A1:B), A1:B }, len(A1:A) ), 
      column(A1:B) - column(A1) + 1 + 1, 
      false 
    ) 
  ) 
)
```

To insert a different number of rows, edit the `2` in the formula.

Comment: That is not what i want. I’ve edited my title/post. The source has no blank rows at all. But i want to output them by adding some blank rows. So image 1 is the source and image 2 is the output.

Comment: Understood. Edited the answer.

Comment: Great. it's perfect.